# IDEA Intellij version 2020.1 - Sonarlint plugin not available in marketplace

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint-intellij

I am unable to find SonarLint plugin on intellij marketplace. Search results show nothing.

IDEA Intellij version 2020.1 -  built April 8 2020
Runtime version - 11.0.6

Any solution/workaround for this issue ?

Comment: Probably it's installed already? it might be migrated from prevoius version.

Comment: Nope.  Not installed .

Comment: Sorry, was checking in the installed tab. Now i can find it in the list. rookie mistake.